# Ting/Ping noise from front wheel around rotor

Tags: mountain-bike

There is a constant ting-ting-ting noise from the front brake/rotor of my mountain bike.  The bike shop said it's the rivets of the floating rotor but I'm not convinced at it happens from the moment I set off, I would only expect it from the rivets as the rotor heats up due to braking.

The pads have been adjusted etc but it's still there.

Any ideas?

Tia

Comment: Does it happen only when the wheel is rotating?

Comment: Hi, if I lift the front and drop it down again while stationary it'll make the sound, or if I bump the frame against something solid it will also make the sound.  It doesn't make the sound when I have the bike over and spin the wheel by hand

Comment: Well that's not the rotor, sounds like press fit fork stanchions moving in the fork crown. I hear it is a common problem with suspension forks. Or maybe the axle moving in the legs?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a noob here, how do I check if it's the press fit stanchions or the axle moving?

Comment: Could also be spoke related, loose spokes, or spokes settling, how old is the bike?

Comment: Does the noise go away if you apply the front brake?

Comment: @Nate W good point

Comment: Hi, yes the noise goes away if I apply the front brake.  Bike is 6 weeks old

Comment: Sounds a little like spoke noise.

Comment: Hmm, well, could be the rotor then. How much float does it have side-side? Does it move rotationally?

Comment: Your bike is **6 weeks old** so its totally under warranty.  Take it to the shop under warranty.

Comment: The rotor feels solid, cannot feel any play in it.  The bike was an online purchase and the shop is far away, to return it I would have to ship it back and as this is my commuter bike that isn't ideal.   So, I was thinking steps to take would be to tighten the spoke say 1/4 turn, try adjusting the pads again and if all else fails then I may look at upgrading the rotors as there are some pretty steep descents on my commute and the stopping power isn't great with these brakes.

Comment: Tick the spokes one after the other with say a screwdriver like they were strings on an instrument and compare the sounds they make. The sound should ideally be identical. If one or more sound deeper, those are less tensioned and may be the cause of the ting-ting sounds.

Comment: Something else to try - have a friend hold the frame with the front wheel just off the ground, Hold forks and push back and forth - if you hear the sound it's the stanchions in the crown.

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus: You can do that without help in the same way you check for play in the steering: Lock the front brake and move the bike back and forth while holding a fingertip to the place that you want to check for play to detect slight movement. You may even hear the ticking noise.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for all your suggestions.  I look to have solved it though.  Turns out it was the rotor hitting the pad, or that's what I believe.  I loosened the brake held the brake lever down and then tightened it back up while still holding the lever and the sound has now gone.